# How to draw Accumulation and Discounting timelines in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

I am an actuarial student and I am currently working on the time value of money in financial mathematics where I am supposed to write a lot of timelines for accumulation and discounting. But I am really finding it hard to draw this in LaTeX. Please, someone, help me out. This is an example of such timelines [image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Have you tried, sometimes,this editor that it creates code in TikZ? https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: I have not tried that code yet.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is tagged with Metapost, here is an effort in MP.  It's wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path timeline;
    timeline = origin -- 260 right;

    pair m[];
    m0 = point 0 of timeline;
    m1 = point 2/9 of timeline;
    m2 = point 5/9 of timeline;
    m3 = point 7/9 of timeline;

    drawarrow timeline;
    for i=0 upto 3:
        draw (down--up) scaled 3 shifted m[i];
    endfor

    interim labeloffset := 6;

    label.bot("\strut $0$", m0) withcolor 2/3 blue;
    label.bot("\strut $k$", m1) withcolor 2/3 blue;
    label.bot("\strut $n$", m2) withcolor 2/3 blue;
    label.bot("\strut $r$", m3) withcolor 2/3 blue;

    label.top("X", m1) withcolor 1/2 red;
    label.top("Y", m2) withcolor 1/2 red;
    label.top("Z", m3) withcolor 1/2 red;

    interim ahangle := 30;
    
    drawarrow (m1 -- m2 
        cutbefore fullcircle scaled 12 shifted m1
        cutafter fullcircle scaled 16 shifted m2)
        shifted 9.6 up withcolor 2/3 blue;
    
    drawarrow (m2 -- m3 
        cutbefore fullcircle scaled 12 shifted m2
        cutafter fullcircle scaled 16 shifted m3)
        shifted 9.6 up withcolor 2/3 blue;

    drawarrow (m1 -- m3) shifted 20 up withcolor 1/2 red;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You can get all the details of syntax here from the resources set out on [the TUG page for Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

One feature to point out is that I have tried to define the drawing in terms of positions along the central time line. So if you changed the time line, the rest of the drawing would change automatically.  So just by changing the second line above to

```
    timeline = origin -- 180 right;
```

you would get this tighter version that would fit in a smaller column.

[image]

The units are PostScript points 72: = 1in,  28.35 = 1cm.

Comment: I should add that you *could* have fancy boxes behind the labels in MP, but I'm not sure that they are worth the effort!  Similarly you *could* make it do those horrible shadows behind the arrows :-)

Comment: actually no need of the boxes.

Comment: This one appears to fit more in what I am working on.

Answer (score 2):

With TikZ. (do you want the boxes more fancy?)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,time/.style={minimum height=5mm,minimum width=6mm,fill=#1,text=white}]
\def\k{1.5} 
\def\n{4}
\def\r{6}
\draw[teal,-latex] (0,0)--(\r+1,0);
\draw[teal] (0,.1)--(0,-.1) node[below=2mm,time=teal]{$0$}
(\k,.1) node[above=2mm,time=red] (x) {$x$}--
(\k,-.1) node[below=2mm,time=teal]{$k$}
(\n,.1) node[above=2mm,time=red] (y) {$y$} --
(\n,-.1) node[below=2mm,time=teal]{$n$}
(\r,.1) node[above=2mm,time=red] (z) {$z$}--
(\r,-.1) node[below=2mm,time=teal]{$r$};
\draw[teal,->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (x)--(y);
\draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (y)--(z);
\draw[red,->,shift={(90:1.3)}] (\k,0)--(\r,0);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Update: removing boxes as OP asked.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,time/.style={minimum height=5mm,minimum width=6mm}]
\def\k{1.5} 
\def\n{4}
\def\r{6}
\draw[teal,-latex] (0,0)--(\r+1,0);
\draw[teal] (0,.1)--(0,-.1) node[below=2mm,time]{$0$}
(\k,.1) node[above=2mm,time,red] (x) {$x$}--
(\k,-.1) node[below=2mm,time]{$k$}
(\n,.1) node[above=2mm,time] (y) {$y$} --
(\n,-.1) node[below=2mm,time]{$n$}
(\r,.1) node[above=2mm,time] (z) {$z$}--
(\r,-.1) node[below=2mm,time]{$r$};
\draw[teal,->] (x)--(y);
\draw[->] (y)--(z);
\draw[red,->,shift={(90:1.3)}] (\k,0)--(\r,0);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a way I could remove those boxes and work with lines. It would appear more appealing, I believe so.

Comment: Is there a way I can modify this code so that I can remove the boxes and have only lines without the boxes? So that it appears like the one below here?

Comment: @IndekuAlex I removed the boxed